# Can't access field of firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue where I am trying to access the name field of a user document in Firestore. Whenever I console.log doc.data() I see the value, but whenever I try to assign doc.data().name to a variable it is either null or undefined. I have a button set up called "t" to try to print out the actual name value. Any ideas on what could be going on here?

```
const MessageClickable=(props)=>{

    const {userID} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [otherName,setOtherName]=useState()
    const [accName, setAccname]= useState([])
    let hello=''

    useEffect(()=>{
        let hello=''
        const subscriber=firebase.firestore().collection('Users')
        .doc(props.chatMembers[0]==userID ? props.chatMembers[1]:userID)
        .get()
        .then((doc)=>{
            console.log(doc.data())//this succesfully prints out my data
            hello=doc.data().name 
        })
        setOtherName(hello)
        
        
    },[])
    
    const t=()=>{
        setOtherName(hello)
        console.log(otherName)//this prints out nothing
    }


    return(
        <View >
            <Button title="press" onPress={t}/>
            
            <Text></Text>
        </View>
    )

}


const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor:'blue'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method is asynchronous and **returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)**. This Promise resolves with the result of the `get()` method call (i.e. a `DocumentSnapshot`) and that result is passed to the `then()` handler.
Therefore it is only within the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) block that you get the value of the `DocumentSnapshot`.

The following should do the trick:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let hello = ''
    const subscriber = firebase.firestore().collection('Users')
    .doc(props.chatMembers[0]==userID ? props.chatMembers[1]:userID)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data())//this succesfully prints out my data
        hello = doc.data().name;
        setOtherName(hello);
    })
      
},[])
```

More explanations [here](https://dev.to/ramonak/javascript-how-to-access-the-return-value-of-a-promise-object-1bck), for example.

Comment: Hello @KiranManicka, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Yes I did thank you so much u helped deepen my understanding of promises and asynchronous calls.